# ILMath.Vec() Appears to be Generation Slightly Wrong Output (Potential Bug?)

Tags: matlab, function, ilnumerics

I'm comparing ILMath.Vec() with MatLab's and I'm seeing significant rounding errors.

For example, if I create a vector (using Start:`0`, Step:`1.2635048525911006`, End:`20700`) for each system:

MatLab: `[Start:Step:End]`

ILNumerics: `Vec<double>(Start, Step, End)`

And then take the average abs difference, I get an average error of `1.56019608343883E-09`. However, I if create the vector by hand (using multiplication), I get an average error of only `3.10973469197506E-13`, 4 magnitudes smaller error.

After looking at ILNumerics' vec function (using Reflector), I think I know why the average error value is so large. The ILMath.vec() function is using addition vs. multiplication. Summing the step value 16,384 times **is not** the same thing as multiplying the step value x N (where N is the current loop count) 16,384 times! The addition's rounding errors add up very quickly!

Please consider fixing this issue.

Comment: Good point! I've added an issue in the ilnumerics bugtracker: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis/view.php?id=197

Comment: Or do some kind of compromise, since addition is much faster than multiplication. Use addition for about 100 or 1000 steps, then rebase using multiplication.